# Can I add Navigation Drawer to my app after I have designed the whole app ? If so, how?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I've designed this android app. Now that it's in it's final stage , I'm thinking of adding a Navigation Drawer. And I intend to add it to every activity. Is that possible somehow ? If yes , please direct me to some tutorial or something.

Comment: It depends on that, you might have created your whole application in Activity. But navigation drawer works with fragments. So you might have to do many changes, because Activity and Fragment have different life cycles.

Comment: here very simple impl. of navigation drawer in the app https://github.com/balduzzi85/it.balduzzi.customnavigationdrawer

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add but you have to do some modifications such as OnDrawerclosed and OnDrawerOpened events.

You can follow the following links-

[first](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

[second](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android)

Comment: Yeah I've visited those links before bro. But I didn't quite get the concept. I'm kinda a newbie to Android development. See, my app has different screens like News, Events, Home etc. Now what I want to do is change the main content of the DrawerLayout according to which item in the ListView I've selected. I'm modifying the Sample Code I got on developer.google.com [ hope that doesn't get me into trouble ;) ]. Can you suggest a few tweaks in that code after taking a look at it ?

Comment: If you wanna take a look @ the code here's the link to my repository. Any help is appreciated.